# Error "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'int'"

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
oldfile = open("buscrash_diversion.uexp", "rb")
l = list(oldfile.read())
out = open("1", "wb")
for i in l:
    out.write(i)
```

If i execute this

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'int'
```

If i execute this

```
import struct
oldfile = open("buscrash_diversion.uexp", "rb")
l = list(oldfile.read())
out = open("1", "wb")
for i in l:
    out.write(struct.pack("b", i))
```

```
struct.error: byte format requires -128 <= number <= 127
```

I can't solve this problem for a week, even if i use "bytearray" it gives the following error

```
TypeError: can assign only bytes, buffers, or iterables of ints in range(0, 256)
```

Where am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integer list is not bytes-like, but you can simply cast it into `bytes`.

```py
oldfile = open("oldfile", 'rb')
l = list(oldfile.read())
out = open("newfile", 'wb')
for i in l:
    out.write(bytes([i]))
```

Although the above should solve your problem, FYI, you should use `struct.pack('B', ...)` for **unsigned byte** (which is [0..255]), `'b'` for **signed byte** (which is [-128..127]).

Answer (score 1):

You open and write to the files in binary mode (the `b` flag in open/write). Remove this flag to be able to write non-byte data

```
oldfile = open("buscrash_diversion.uexp", "r")
l = list(oldfile.read())
out = open("1", "w")
for i in l:
    out.write(i)
```

Comment: It's a binary file, so it will give encoding error.